# Getting error while starting OpenTSDB

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, opentsdb

I am trying to use OpenTSDB over HBase in stand alone mode. Below is my hbase-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/root/HBASE/hbase</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/root/HBASE/zookeeper</value>
</property>
```

I am starting hbase by below command

**./bin/start-hbase.sh**

When I am trying to start OpenTSDB I am getting following error logs in *opentsdb.log*

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_85]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744) ~ [na:1.7.0_85]
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1143) ~  [zookeeper-3.3.6.jar:3.3.6-1366786]
02:55:53.767 INFO  [ClientCnxn.startConnect] - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
02:55:53.769 WARN  [ClientCnxn.run] - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

When is try *jps* immediately after starting OpenTSDB I get following output

```
[root@Flume_Server hbase-0.94.8]# jps
12321 TSDMain
12359 Jps
12085 HMaster
759 Main
```

but after some times I am getting below output from *jps*

```
[root@Flume_Server conf]# jps
12476 Jps
12439 TSDMain
759 Main
```

Following is the error I get in hbase log

```
2015-10-13 05:14:31,875 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine: Failed to start master
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1099)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1075)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.JVMClusterUtil.startup(JVMClusterUtil.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.LocalHBaseCluster.startup(LocalHBaseCluster.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2079)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:744)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1206)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1050)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Looks like your HBase instance is shutting down. Can you post the interesting bits of the hbase log ?

Comment: Hi @Nicholas, I have edited the question with error logs from hbase log file.

Comment: Hey, that hbase error doesn't look like a standalone server error. Can you review the procedure for standalone server setup ?

Comment: @Nicholas I am referring following link https://archanaschangale.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/installing-apache-hbase-on-ubuntu-for-standalone-mode/ to setup standalone server. I will check it again whether I am exactly following the steps.